# Session is not working on my site

Tags: php, session-variables

I Am using a session on a website and I am unable to take the data on the other page. I have used the code on other host and its working fine on other host so I think that the host problem.

**The code I used to save the session is:**

```
session_start();

$_SESSION["std_id"] = 'rst';

echo "<pre>";
print_r($_SESSION);
echo "</pre>";
```

**And I am retrieving it on the other page with this code:**

```
session_start();
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_SESSION);
echo "</pre>";
```

As I said its working fine on other `host` as well as on `localhost`, so that is the server issue, but I need to keep the login info of the user as we use to maintain login record through session.

We have installed Joomla on that site and its working fine its maintaining all the login info and every thing.

Can anyone suggest me the solution other than changing the host :)
Thanks.

**Edited:**
I can't show the host name as due to some reason.
The domain I am using is a sub-domain for a University department and the main site is of University site, and I am using this code under a new folder at sub domain.

Comment: When exactly is it not working? Can you show what host names you are using in those cases?

Comment: Are the pages on the same host? on the same domain?

Comment: is your second page on a different sub-domain?

Comment: Firefox Liveheaders; determine cookie presence. Enable error reporting. Then google the error message.

Comment: I am not getting any error message I am even getting the session id when I use `echo session_id('std_id')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you get any errors in your error log or in php error reporting ([error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php))?
like `"No session exists - writing to test_value"`

you can also test your current session directory if its writeable:

```
$writeable = is_writable(ini_get("session.save_path"));
```

one solution is to `change your session directory` with this: 
(create the **/tmp** directory `by hand` in your root)

```
ini_set("session.save_path","/tmp");
```

or to your **.htaccess**

```
php_value session.save_path /tmp
```

and give `0777` permission in that **/tmp** directory, which must be in your root.

Comment: Yes the session directory is not writable, can you tell me where is that /tmp directory in my sub domain?
I made it writable but again that session is not saving.

Answer (score 1):

As I see in your codes, everything looks fine. You do not need to change your host just contact to your host provider. I've had a similiar issue with a host before. If you contact them, they will edit your php.ini file to allow you to start sessions.

**Note :** Not every host providers allow users to use many features of PHP. You have it ask them to set it on. They turn these features off to save CPU usage.

Comment: I still haven't heard of one turning off sessions though.

Comment: Like I said, I've had the similar problem before. And it's not only sessions, some host providers turn off so many features of PHP to save CPU usage. Specially if it's a cloud hosting.

Comment: They are providing the session as I think because when I `echo phpinfo();` it show that session is on in the host.